# JAVA package import in python

Tags: java, python-3.x, jython-2.7

I am getting an error while importing a package (name "ner" made in java), I am trying to import the package in python as:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jythonex.py", line 2, in 
    from ner import NER
ImportError: No module named ner

ner has a class named NER and class NER has a method called nlp()
my python code is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from ner import NER
n = NER()
testString = "أشاد رئيس مجلس علماء باكستان الشيخ طاهر محمود أشرفي "
n.nlp(testString)
```

what am I doing wrong, if any alternate method please let me know, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import Java packages in Python at least the regular distribution of Python. If you really need to use java code/libraries from your python script then [you should look into Jython](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jython/jython_importing_java_libraries.htm).

Comment: I was using jython earlier but it was throwing the above error.